# MySQL multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysql

So here is my question. I have a table for song for URL titile and type. I have an user input fields where the user can choose what type of music he wants. As we all know 1 song never is never only 1 type so every song has more than 1 type. So my question is there a way that i can search for what the user has picked.

For expml:

the user is searching for: punk, techno.

in the table there is a song with type: punk techno and rap

I'd like this row to be selected

Comment: What does your data look like? You don't have multiple types in one column, do you?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for ORs in the WHERE clause of the SQL statement. 
`SELECT song FROM music WHERE type='punk' OR type='techno' OR type='any_other_kind_of_music'`

Comment: you have different table for the types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use many-many relationship, so you have to create an "intermediary" table called something like "song_type" with these columns:

- id (this column is optional if you create a combined primary key with the next to columns)
- song_id
- type_id

This way you can have multiple songs related to multiple types.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d9a0/7) is the idea :) Hope I helped :)

Comment: very interesting. I'll try it. Thnx!